# Comparing types of generic lists

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to compare two `IList<T>` by their Type. Both lists have the same `T` and therefore I thought they should have the same type.

In debug-mode in Visual Studio in the tooltip I can read the types of both and it is the same.

But `Equals()` ant the `==` Operator return both `false`.

Can anyone explanin this weired behavior?

Little Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        IList<string> list2 = new List<string>();

        var type1 = list1.GetType();
        var type2 = typeof(IList<string>);

        if (type1.Equals(type2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("equal");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("non equal");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

==> non equal

**Edit:**
I coose a bad Example, this one shows the way I was trying to to it.

I'm using .Net 3.5

Comment: Did you actually try your exact example? I'd expect that to work...

Comment: I guess, you will need to compile the code for the debugger to step onto right line.

Comment: I assume that typeof(List<string>) always returns a reference to the same instance of the class Type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you're comparing two types: `List<string>` and `IList<string>`. They're not the same type, and I don't know why you'd expect them to be the same.

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but you might want to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx). For example, in your example,

```
Console.WriteLine(type2.IsAssignableFrom(type1));
```

will print True.

---

Answer from before the edit...

Unable to reproduce:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IList<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        IList<string> list2 = new List<string>();

        var type1 = list1.GetType();
        var type2 = list2.GetType();

        Console.WriteLine(type1.Equals(type2)); // Prints True
    }
}
```

Is it possible that in your *real* code, they're both implementations of `IList<string>`, but *different* implementations, e.g.

```
IList<string> list1 = new List<string>();
IList<string> list2 = new string[5];
```

That will show the types being different, because one is a `List<string>` and the other is a `string[]`.

Comment: The new Example is almost the real situation, just shortend a little

Comment: @Tokk: Have edited my answer. It's not clear what sort of equality you're looking for, but you're comparing two different types...

Answer (score 2):

That is because list1 is `List<string>` ( so type1 is `typeof(List<string>)` aswell ) and type 2 is `typeof(IList<string>)`. Notice `IList<string>` vs `List<string>`. Neither `list1` nor `list2` is `IList<string>`, they are `List<T>`'s, which derives from `IList<T>`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above this is indeed due to the reason that `List<string>` and `IList<string>` are not the same type.

If your goal is to determine whether your type implements an interface (i.e. `IList<string>`) you can do so with reflection:

```
 if (type1.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IList<string>)))
     Console.WriteLine("type1 implements IList<string>");
```